# How to find duplicates numbers in a column

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a table consisting of 2 columns name and id. I want to check if there's duplicate id's or not. Is there a solution?

Comment: When there is only numbers in ID, the records are not too much, you may `click a cell then go to Layout tab > Sort`, set ID for Sort by and Then by, and then observe if there are duplicates. 
When the amount of data is large, it's best copy table to Excel, then add a column to use [countif function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) to find duplicate ID. When the number is bigger than 1, there are [duplicate ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GZUD.jpg).

Answer (score -1):

This article does a good job of covering it.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-and-remove-duplicates-00e35bea-b46a-4d5d-b28e-66a552dc138d

TL;DR:

> Click Data > Remove Duplicates, and then Under Columns, check or
> uncheck the columns where you want to remove the duplicates.

Comment: This is for Excel not Word

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the tag. I still recommend this though. Copy the table into Excel or Google Sheets and then back over. The only way to do it with Word is to write a VBA script.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/5499-word-table-remove-duplicates.html

Comment: The code does not work as the OP states, it will remove duplicate rows but not columns. VBA arrays are not flexible, there are not many methods there should be makes it very hard.